# C Makefile error: ld returned 1 exit

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors

My teacher is not the best at explain C so I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the connection of makefiles. I have already added the code for complex.c, complex.h, and main.c. I'm just having trouble compiling it all using the make command. I followed the example on the powerpoint he handed up and I don't understand why its failing to get to complex.

makefile

```
complex: main.o complex.o
    gcc -o complex main.o complex.o
main.o: main.c complex.h
    gcc -c main.c -lm
complex.o: complex.c complex.h
    gcc -c complex.c -lm
clean:
    rm*.o complex
    ls
```

main.o

```
main.o: complex.h
    gcc -c main.c
```

complex.o

```
complex.o: complex.h
    gcc -c complex.c
```

Error

```
mason% make
gcc -o complex main.o complex.o 
ld: fatal: file main.o: unknown file type
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to complex
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `complex'
```

Comment: It seems quite odd that `gcc` wouldn't recognize `main.o` as an object file. What environment (OS, &c.) are you running this on?

Comment: @Dolda2000 I'm using mac

Comment: You should be running the `make clean` every time.  It looks like `main.o` exists but is the wrong system or corrupt (or incorrect).

Comment: I don't think it should actually matter, but you're supposed to give the library arguments (`-lm`, that is) to the command producing the executable, not the commands producing the object files. Just for the sake of ruling it out, please correct that and see if it makes a difference. Also what @SteveHarris said.

Comment: @Dolda2000 I tried it , but it didn't work. My professor says that -lm is used so that the compiler recognizes the #include <math.h>

Comment: It probably does matter, since using the `-lm` arguments on the object probably invokes the loader.   @Dolda2000, the `-l*` argument only needs to be on the final executable builds.  Object files will contain unresolved references from the *.h files that the loader will resolve during final compilation.  Anytime something uses "math.o" for example, it would have to also include `-lm` in its final compilation.

Comment: @SteveHarris: Isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: @struggling: `-lm` is indeed so that you can use the functions from `math.h`, but my point is that it has to go on the command that produces the final executable (where it's missing in your makefile), and not on the commands that produce the object files (where your makefile has it).

Comment: Welp, sorry, my bad, it seems I completely missed the `main.o` and `complex.o` contents you had posted in the question. Being so, @merlin2011's answer is correct.

Comment: @Dolda2000 with that method it did get rid of my errors, but it didn't compile my code. It just prints 'main.o' is up to date.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have put Makefile fragments inside `main.o` and `complex.o`. These should be generated **by the compiler, not by you**.

Delete these files, and `make` again.

Additionally, your `make clean` rule is missing a space.

```
clean:
    rm *.o complex
    ls
```

One more thing. No need for `-lm` in the compile lines.

```
main.o: main.c complex.h
    gcc -c main.c
complex.o: complex.c complex.h
    gcc -c complex.c
```

You should add `-lm` at the linking phase.

```
complex: main.o complex.o
    gcc -o complex main.o complex.o -lm
```

Comment: I'm suppose to have a final executable "complex" that depends on linking main.o and complex.o together. My professor also said I had to use -lm in the makefile so the compiler recognizes the #include <math.h>.

Comment: @struggling, You `-lm` at the linking phase when you actually build `complex`.

Comment: I did everything, but i don't know why i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The "Makefile" defines and controls the build dependencies.

For example, you can't build the main executable binary without first building the binary object/module files that go with it.  In this case, those are `main.o` and `complex.o`.

Generally any object file you need also needs a rule (though some rules can use "wildcards" to build more).

This is all rather academic.  Best to take errors at their word and try to disprove them (this one basically says that main.o exists and is incorrect).  In this case the hypothesis that main.o exists is supported by the fact that it didn't compile when you ran the make command.

Until you learn more you could invoke "make" using "targets".  Like: `make clean` and `make complex`.  It might help bring clarity.

A lot of makefiles put an "all" target to sort of reset the build.  That then depends on "clean" and the executable and library targets.  Like:

```
all: clean complex
```

So then you "make all" to clean and build.

A good tutorial is here.  [Mrbook Makefile Tutorial](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today in my uni project. I fixed it by deleting the functions i had declared and redeclared them under different names (all were **VOID**). I dunno the actual reason why it happened but this is a **practical** solution that worked for me!

NOTE: i also go rid of a **SWITCH** that i had used and resorted to **if , else if , else** , which might be a more plausible explanation